# Apps that interact with each other through Bluetooth on different android devises?

Tags: android

I want to understand is it possible to make an app that, after installing and running on 2 different devices, connect with each other in a way, for example, there is a button and a text view in the app and when I click the button on my device, it updates the text view in the other device's app, and same the other way round.

If yes, then please guide me what's it called and where can I read and learn about it.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the section on [Connectivity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/index.html) on the Android Developer page. It has a few solutions to this.

In your case, there is a [Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices) section on communicating between devices. Essentially you have one device act as a server and another as a client.

A description of what is involved as a server from that page.

> **Connecting as a server**
>
> When you want to connect two devices, one must act as a server by
>   holding an open BluetoothServerSocket. The purpose of the server
>   socket is to listen for incoming connection requests and when one is
>   accepted, provide a connected BluetoothSocket. When the
>   BluetoothSocket is acquired from the BluetoothServerSocket, the
>   BluetoothServerSocket can (and should) be discarded, unless you want
>   to accept more connections.

Now you connect to the server phone with your client phone.

> **Connecting as a client**
>
> In order to initiate a connection with a remote device (a device
>   holding an open server socket), you must first obtain a
>   BluetoothDevice object that represents the remote device. (Getting a
>   BluetoothDevice is covered in the above section about Finding
>   Devices.) You must then use the BluetoothDevice to acquire a
>   BluetoothSocket and initiate the connection.

Another option on newer phones can make use of [WiFi Direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) which is built for what you're trying to do as well.